# What do you call continous transformations that preserve the finite group structure?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

A number of years ago I studied a preon model (Journal of Mathematical Physics 38:3414-3426, 1997) in which the preons interacted like group elements.  I thought it curious that you could sometimes define continuous transformations over the group elements which preserved the group structure.

Specifically, find a continuous family of V such that [edit] if we define $g_i$ as the elements of the finite group,

${g_i}' = V g_i$

if $g_i g_j = g_k$  then ${g_i}' {g_j}' = {g_k}'$

[edit] V is continuous in the sense that the difference between two different transformations can be arbitrarily small.  If represented as a matrix, the matrix elements can be arbitrarily small.  I know there can be permutations, for which this isn't true, but I wasn't interested in those.  I was representing the group elements as unit vectors in N-space where N is the group size, and the transformations as NxN complex matrices.

I was using complex numbers, and in that case at least, there aren't any such continuous transformations if the finite group is abelian.  (That's why I don't think the model is physical.)  Some non-abelian groups admit transformations isomorphic to SU(2) and SU(3), and of other things.

I'm confident that this is well-known, but I'm not deeply familiar with the research in group algebras, and I'm not sure where to look to find out more--e.g. if there's a pattern to this.

[edit] My apologies for a lack of precision in the initial question.

[edit2] Maybe a concrete example is in order
The simplest non-abelian group has the Cayley table that I specify as
$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
X&0&1&2&3&4&5 \\ \hline
0&0&1&2&3&4&5 \\
1&1&2&0&4&5&3 \\
2&2&0&1&5&3&4 \\
3&3&5&4&0&2&1 \\
4&4&3&5&1&0&2 \\
5&5&4&3&2&1&0 
\end{array}$

If an element in the group algebra is represented by a vector,
with $g_0$ = (1,0,0,0,0,0), $g_1$=(0,1,0,0,0,0), etc, then if a, b,
and c are infinitesimal small changes, $\bar{1}$ + $\delta V$ is a
transformation which, when applied to the group elements, gives new
elements whose products are isomorphic to those of the original group
elements.  $\bar{1}$ is the identity 6x6 matrix, and

$\delta V$ = $ \begin{array}{cccccc}
0&0&0 &0&0&0\\
0&0&0 &a&-b&-a+b\\
0&0&0 &-a&b&a-b\\
0&a&-a& 0&c&-c \\
0&-b&b&-c&0&c \\
0&-a+b&a-b&c&-c&0 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: What is $V$, what is $g_i$, what's a "continuous transformation over the group elements", etc etc

Comment: I guess what you are looking is a continuous family of group automorphisms. Of course this depend on the group and the topology in the set of the automorphisms. If the group is finite then obviusly the set of automorphisms is finite.

Comment: https://msp.org/pjm/1978/76-1/pjm-v76-n1-p15-s.pdf this may help.

Comment: I'm starting to read that.  Thanks.

Comment: This question is a good illustration of the kinds of problems that can arise when physicists and mathematicians try to talk to each other. In language comfortable for mathematicians, I *think* the question is: let $G$ be a finite group and let $A$ be its group algebra. Consider the automorphism group of $A$. What can the connected component of Aut$(A)$ containing the identity look like?

Comment: And a "translation" is exactly what I'm looking for, so that I can know _what_ to look for.  Thank you.

Comment: James, with a -2 score this question may not get much more attention. I'd suggest you post my "translation" as a separate question under the title "automorphism group of a finite group algebra". You could include a comment that "Nik Weaver asked me to post this separately" to address any concern about double posting.

Comment: I'm reading over some of the references to make sure I have a handle on the meaning here, but I will take your advice.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A nice example is in any algebra, by definition multiplying by a arbitary element is an automorphism of it group structure. So the algebra is the family you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, except when it isn't. You need the element to be invertible in the algebra.

Comment: I meant just a morphism from $G$  to $G$ not an automorphism, which is what he is asking for. Sorry, this are just words, my idea is correct is a shame you couldn´t read this from what I wrote.

Comment: This is just the distributive law common!!!